# Mongo Query - Filter on nested array and return documents that do not contain a specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```
{
  "_id": 0,
  "games": {
     "gamesList": [
        {
          "franchiseName": "Tekken",
          "genre": "Fighting",
          "gamesInFranchise": [
              {
                 "name": "Tekken 7",
                 "releaseDate": "03/18/2015",
                 "co-op": true,
                 "platforms": [ 
                     "playstation 3",
                     "xbox 360"
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "name": "Tekken 6",
                 "releaseDate": "11/26/2007",
                 "co-op": true
              },
              {
                 "name": "Tekken 5",
                 "releaseDate": "01/01/2004",
                 "co-op": true
              },
           ]
        },
        .................
     ]
  }
}
```

I would like to filter documents based on specific "_id" that do not have the property "platforms". So essentially, the result would ideally look like this:

```
{
  "_id": 0,
  "games": {
     "gamesList": [
        {
          "franchiseName": "Tekken",
          "genre": "Fighting",
          "gamesInFranchise": [
              {
                 "name": "Tekken 6",
                 "releaseDate": "11/26/2007",
                 "co-op": true
              },
              {
                 "name": "Tekken 5",
                 "releaseDate": "01/01/2004",
                 "co-op": true
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

I tried using aggregation specifically with projection/filter query, but I can't seem to reach "platforms" to check if it exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple embedded array before reaching platforms.
You have to use the aggregation framework to deal with them.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "games.gamesList": {
        $map: {
          input: "$games.gamesList",
          as: "franchise",
          in: {
            "franchiseName": "$$franchise.franchiseName",
            "genre": "$$franchise.genre",
            "gamesInFranchise": {
              $filter: {
                input: "$$franchise.gamesInFranchise",
                as: "gameInFranchise",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    null,
                    {
                      $ifNull: [
                        "$$gameInFranchise.platforms",
                        null
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I used $addFields to keep your other fields safe.

> Note that you have to describe whole element in th 'in' field of
>   '$map' operator.

The first [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator is relative to the first level array, and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to the second level array.

[$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) is the trick to check if element exists, or return something (here set to null). By checking the equality (or not equality) with null, you can check if the element exists

[You can test the query here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sSdEDJddo0C)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I should've specified a bit more, but, let's say there are more objects in 'gamesList' array that have the 'platforms' field, then it will return the document like this:
 {
          "franchiseName": "Tekken",
          "gamesInFranchise": [],
          "genre": "Fighting"
        }
is there a way to exclude this from the result? As I would like to just retain documents that do not have 'platforms', and if it does have 'platforms' the object should not be included in 'gamesList'

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up doing another filter and a condition to return 'gamesInFranchise' that has length > 0.

Comment: If there is a more efficient way, I definitely would like to know. Seems like filtering a second time isn't the best approach.

Comment: I am so glad that I found this answer, its the best and nicest way possible out there as it gives you the freedom to do anything with that data, and you can do the same method in any number of nested levels.